# Kafka connect dead letter queue and Elasticsearch sink connector problem

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I will keep this as short as possible;

I have a kafka connect cluster using json serialization, we post one kafka connector with elasticsearchsinkconnector class to gather data from topics ignoring keys and schemas. We use confluent-5.5.0 and elasticsearchsinkconnector plugin version is also 5.5.0, but I also tried this at local with 11.x version of elasticsearchsinkconnector plugin.

What I am experiencing with the errors sink connector comes by and what messages it sends to dead letter queue is quite weird. If the error in hand is a serialization error, like If i try to send a simple string "this is a message" to my topic and give errors.tolerance: all with a dead letter queue topic defined It in fact sends the message to the dlq-topic, because it cannot serialize the message which comes from the producer, which is fine.

But lets say my elastic index has a field "number" and its mapping type is strictly integer. When I produce a log containing {"number": "this is not an integer"} message gets to the broker no problem, it gets consumed by the sinkconnector, but when it is time to actually index the document into the elasticsearch index, It throws a json parsing error because of the mapping configurations.

Kafka connector is tolerating errors so it keeps working just fine, but I see no messages in the dead letter queue, the json document {"number": "this is not an integer"} just disappears in space. Is there a way to get messages which got errors on client end to be written into the dead letter queue?

I tried this with elasticsearchsink connector plugin version 11.x as well.

Comment: Does it fully disappear, or is an exception logged in the Connect worker output? AFAIK, the DLQ is only for catching errors internal to the Connect API, not any external client exceptions. You may want to look at the source code for the Elasticsearch connector to verify that

Comment: Yes, it does log an error in connect logs. Generally it says a field is missing or an object cannot be parsed due to mapping etc. But in general these logs do not include the index and/or the doc which triggered it. And if you cannot see the corrupted message in the dlq it makes it very hard to debug the problem.